# Efficient multi-selection algorithm

Tags: selection

I have to implement an algorithm that solves the multi-selection problem.
The multiselection problem is:

> Given a set S of n elements drawn from a linearly ordered set, and a set $K = {k_{1}, >k_{2},...,k_{r}}$ of positive integers between 1 and n, the multiselection problem is to >select the $k_{i}th$ smallest element for all values of i, $1 \le i \le r$

I need to solve the average case on $ \theta(n log p) $.
I've found a paper that implements the solution I need, but it assumes that there are no repeated numbers on the set S. The problem is that I can't assume that and I don't know how to adapt the algorithm of that paper to support repeated numbers.
The paper is here: http://www.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa/~suwaiyel/publications/multiselection_parCom.pdf 
and the algorithm is on the second page. Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Please proof-read your question.  It appears that you have some editing issues (e.g., stray `>`'s have crept in) and some sub-optimal use of Latex.  Also, what is $p$?  The parameter $p$ is not defined anywhere.  Do you mean $\Theta(n \lg r)$?

Comment: Checkout ESA 2013 proceedings for the paper "Theory and Implementation of Online Multiselection Algorithms", by me and my coauthors.